# Variable database setting Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm searching a way to create a variable database in Cakephp.
I'm creating a website in wich the database setting (user, pass, db) depends of the user who logg's in. The database settings come from another database.
Thanks in advance,

Aäron

-- ANSWER

Thanks for your quick reply.
I know how to switch between databases, but the database settings have to be variable.
Example

```
   $db = $this->DB_SET['DB_SET']['db']; //from model DB_SET the database 
    $db_login= $this->DB_SET['DB_SET']['login'];
    $db_host= $this->DB_SET['DB_SET']['host'];
    $db_pass= $this->DB_SET['DB_SET']['pass'];
    var $db2 = array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => $db_host,
            'login' => $db_login,
            'password' => $db_pass,
            'database' => $db,
            'prefix' => '',
            'encoding' => 'UTF8',
            'port' => '',
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to create database connections on the fly, you may want to use [`ConnectionManager::create()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/connection-manager#method-ConnectionManagercreate).

```
// get logged in user's id and create a connection for them
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
ConnectionManager::create("user_$id_db", array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => $db_host,
  'login' => $db_login,
  'password' => $db_pass,
  'database' => $db,
  'prefix' => '',
  'encoding' => 'UTF8',
  'port' => '',
));
```

Then set your models to use it when you're ready.

```
// get logged in user's id and use their connection
$id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$this->Model->setDataSource("user_$id_db");
```